# VB: DataGridView

Tags: winforms, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

Bom dia.

Tenho o problema de o design da tabela não actualizar.

O Design:

```
Private Sub DataGridClientsDesign() 'Procedimento que contem o novo estilo da datagrid
    Me.tabelaprocurar.DataMember = "Empregados" 'Nome da tabela associada no datagrid
    Me.tabelaprocurar.ReadOnly = False 'Coloca o datagrid apenas para leitura
    Dim GridStyle As New DataGridTableStyle 'Cria um novo estilo do datagrid
    GridStyle.MappingName = "Empregados" 'Associa a relacao da tabela clientes com a da base de dados
    Dim nEmpCol As New DataGridTextBoxColumn 'define a variavel do tipo DataGridTextBoxColumn
    nEmpCol.MappingName = "nEmp" 'atribui um campo da tabela
    nEmpCol.HeaderText = "nEmp" 'atribui um nome à coluna
    nEmpCol.Width = 110 'define tamanho coluna
    GridStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(nEmpCol) 'adiciona coluna
    Dim nomeCol As New DataGridTextBoxColumn
    nomeCol.MappingName = "nome"
    nomeCol.HeaderText = "Nome"
    nomeCol.Width = 110
    GridStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(nomeCol)
    Dim localidadeCol As New DataGridTextBoxColumn
    localidadeCol.MappingName = "localidade"
    localidadeCol.HeaderText = "Localidade"
    localidadeCol.Width = 110
    GridStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(localidadeCol)
    Dim telefoneCol As New DataGridTextBoxColumn
    telefoneCol.MappingName = "telefone"
    telefoneCol.HeaderText = "Telefone"
    telefoneCol.Width = 110
    GridStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(telefoneCol)
    Dim emailCol As New DataGridTextBoxColumn
    emailCol.MappingName = "email"
    emailCol.HeaderText = "Email"
    emailCol.Width = 110
    GridStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(emailCol)
    Dim generoCol As New DataGridTextBoxColumn
    generoCol.MappingName = "genero"
    generoCol.HeaderText = "Genero"
    generoCol.Width = 110
    GridStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(generoCol)
    Dim sectorCol As New DataGridTextBoxColumn
    sectorCol.MappingName = "sector"
    sectorCol.HeaderText = "Sector"
    sectorCol.Width = 110
    GridStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(sectorCol)
End Sub
```

Mesmo alterando os campos pretendidos, este não actualizada.

Agradecia a vossa ajuda.

Obrigado.

Comment: Alguem me pode ajudar?

Comment: Mas em qual parte do código você esta adicionando o estilo que você criou a sua datagridview?